# getting 500 internal error after restarting IIS and Windows SharePoint Services Web Application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am getting 500 internal error after restarting IIS and Windows SharePoint Services Web Application.All the Urls are displaying this same error.

Comment: Go to Windows Event Viewer and find the SharePoint errors, then post the specifics of the error. Can't help you much otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The event viewer is the best bet. Also, you might be having a problem where a 32 bit dll is being invoked, but IIS is not allowing 32 bit applications. This can be fixed by going into iis, selecting the App pool, advanced, enable 32 bit apps.

Otherwise, event log is best bet.